# Multi address array Google maps Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

There is something wrong with my for loop or array but I don't know where.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

How does the loop should be to work properly?
http://jsfiddle.net/hugpablo/uLza5va6/1/

```
var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        // Multiple addresses
        var addresses = [
      ["First Place", "Colonia providencia, Guadalajara, Jalisco, México"],
      ["Second Place", "Colonia Ayuntamiento, Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico"],
      ["Third Place", "Colonia Moderna, Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico"],
      ["Fourth Place", "Colonia Santa Edwiges, Jalisco, Mexico"]
      ];

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        // Loop through our array of addresses & place each one on the map  
        for(var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++ ) {
            geocoder.geocode( { "address": addresses[i][1] }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                var lat      = location.lat();
                var lng      = location.lng();
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(position);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: addresses[i][0],
                    icon: icon
                });
            };
        });
            // Automatically center the map fitting all addresses on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        };
// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(5);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
```

Comment: I think the Google methods are asynchronous and they are completing after your for loop is complete. At that point i=4 and that index in your array does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  When the callback runs `i==addresses.length` which is not a valid entry in your array.  This is usually solved using function closure.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
};

// Display a map on the page
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Multiple addresses
var addresses = [
  ["First Place", "Colonia providencia, Guadalajara, Jalisco, México"],
  ["Second Place", "Colonia Ayuntamiento, Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico"],
  ["Third Place", "Colonia Moderna, Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico"],
  ["Fourth Place", "Colonia Santa Edwiges, Jalisco, Mexico"]
];

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

// Loop through our array of addresses & place each one on the map  
for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  createMarker(i);

  // Automatically center the map fitting all addresses on the screen
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
};
// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
  this.setZoom(5);
  google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});

function createMarker(i) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    "address": addresses[i][1]
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {

      var location = results[0].geometry.location;
      var lat = location.lat();
      var lng = location.lng();
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      bounds.extend(position);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: addresses[i][0],
        // icon: icon
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    };
  });
}
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 535px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: where exactly should I use function closure? thanks in advance!